How to access functions of pallet-assets from custom pallet?
I want to use the functions of pallet-asset like decrease_balance and Assets storage in our custom pallet.
How I can perform this operation?
Thanks

loosely couple Assets pallet with your custom pallet using fungibles::Unbalanced trait. Then, simply T::Assets::decrease_balance() inside your pallet.

Or the same but tightly coupled, so #[pallet::config] trait Config: pallet_assets::Config { .. } .
